Find $ \lim_{x\to+\infty} \cos^{2}(\sqrt{x+4})-\cos^{2}(\sqrt{x+1}) $

Find
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty} \cos^{2}(\sqrt{x+4})-\cos^{2}(\sqrt{x+1})
$$

My intuition tells me that the limit is zero, because the cosine function is bounded and the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x+4} - \sqrt{x+1}$ converges to zero,  but I don't know right now the trick that I should use to justify it. Can someone give me a small hint? I've thought about using a Taylor series but the arithmetic gets really messy.

you could also use MVT here

We have that
$$\cos^{2}(\sqrt{x+4})-\cos^{2}(\sqrt{x+1})=$$
$$=\left[\cos(\sqrt{x+4})-\cos(\sqrt{x+1})\right]\left[\cos(\sqrt{x+4})+\cos(\sqrt{x+1})\right]$$
and by sum to product identity
$$\cos(\sqrt{x+4})-\cos(\sqrt{x+1}) =-2\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+4}+\sqrt{x+1}}2\right)\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-\sqrt{x+1}}2\right)$$
with $\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-\sqrt{x+1}}2\right) \to 0.$

More in general for any $N \in\mathbb Z$
$$\cos^{N}(f(x))-\cos^{N}(g(x)) \to 0$$
whenever $f(x)-g(x)\to 2k\pi$ for any $k \in\mathbb Z $.

Thank you. I had tried that but I didn’t remember that identity to efectively bound the limit.

This is the well known sum to product identity! We can also generalize the result

Hint: Use
$$ \cos 2A-\cos 2B=-2\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B). $$

Thank you! The right hand side of that identity is the key because you get $\sin(\sqrt{x+4}-\sqrt{x+1})$ which converges to zero due to the continuity of the sine function, and the other piece is bounded, thererefore the product converges to zero and that gives the limit I was finding.

@MrGran, you are right.

$\textbf{Hint:}$
$$\cos^2(\sqrt{x+a}) = \cos^2\left(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x}}\right) \approx \cos^2\left(\sqrt{x}+\frac{a}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)$$
as $x\to\infty$, and
$$\cos^2(\alpha) - \cos^2(\beta) = \cos(2\alpha) -\cos(2\beta)$$

"The answer is not zero." I disagree. Check that one sine factor tends to zero and the other remains bounded, therefore ... .

@OscarLanzi yes you're right, it does converge to $0$ - thanks for the catch

The beginning of an approach using series:
\begin{align*}
\cos\left(\sqrt{x+a}\right) 
&= \cos\left(\sqrt x\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{x}}\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\sqrt x\left(1+\frac{a}{2x}+O(1/x^2)\right)\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\sqrt x + \frac{a}{2\sqrt x} + O(1/x^{3/2})\right) \\
&= \cos\sqrt x - \frac{a}{2\sqrt x}\sin\sqrt x + O(1/x) \\
\end{align*}
